# align text-line to bottom

Tags: css

CSS aligns the text in the middle of the line, but I'd like to have the text aligned to the bottom of the line. Best explained with a picture:

Like it should be:
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-L1TBqTxEVHI/UDPVEOnFY7I/AAAAAAAAAH4/GHZHt776wmg/s145/CD-Manual_Stand_Mai_2011_Verlinkungen.pdf%2520%2528Seite%2520135%2520von%2520248%2529.jpg

Like it is:
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-0SiQqqkHD9k/UDPVNvTA2NI/AAAAAAAAAIA/2VudybQxnDE/s45/CSSEdit.jpg

Vertical-align doesn't work, it does only work for nested elements and not the entire text. Where's the trick? :)

Here is the code: [jsfiddle.net/vmadd](http://jsfiddle.net/vmadd)

Comment: can you show us some code? a fiddle perhaps?

Comment: Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/vmadd/ especially at the bottom you can see the problem. "Name" is to close to the line -- and the cleanest solution would be to align the text to the lines bottom (for the hole document.)

Answer (score 1):

Try `line-height: 100%`
that should fix you problem.

Comment: I use a custom line-hight. It's for sophisticated typography.

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually see what you are after. There is no such thing as a baseline alignment or something in standard css (to my knowledge). I don't realy see what that would change in the layout eather.

As for the footer, if you just want some more space between the line and the text, there are plenty af ways to achieve this. Something like this:

```
div.layoutGridBottom p {
    padding-top: 10mm;
}
```

Should do the trick. Or even better, declare a special class for things you want to have some top padding, and apply it to the elements you want. As said, there are dozens of ways to achieve this (line-height, margin-top, insert blank div, make the line have padding bottom, ...) If you wrote that css yourself, I'm surprised this causes you problems...

Comment: That's than the fiddle solution; anyway thanks for helping! :)